# How to pass a variable to the selector and the python function, which variable will be declared at the test level?

Tags: python, selenium, variables, xpath, automation

Could you please help me with a test scenario?
I'm starting to automate a project using python and selenium organized in page objects.
I have separated file for the locators, separated files for different pages (so far, only 2 pages) and separated file for the test itself.

In the locators file, I write my selector, which contains a variable. I need it to be variable because later on I will have more than 10 selectors with the same Xpath, where only the text changes. So, this text I set it as a variable.

```
class AgreementPageLocators:
.........
MAIN_SEARCH_PK = (By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(text(), {variable})]')
```

In the "agreement" page, I define the action what should be done. Basically is to add something from a dropdown box. Marked in blue, is where I call the locator which contains the variable.
[image]

In my test file, I call the agreements method, where I define the variable:

```
# add agreement if it doesn't exist
if len(browser.find_elements(*AgreementPageLocators.AGREEMENT_CRIME)) == 0:
    agreement_page = AgreementPage(browser)
    agreement_page.agreements(variable='text1')
else:
    pass
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as my test returns:

MAIN_SEARCH_PK = (By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(text(), {variable})]')
E   NameError: name 'variable' is not defined

By putting the desired text instead of the variable in the selector, everything works fine. But I want to make it dynamically and not rewriting lots of times the same function just with different selectors.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score -1):

Try to define `MAIN_SEARCH_PK` as

```
MAIN_SEARCH_PK = (By.XPATH, '//div[contains(text(), "{}")]')
```

and

```
def agreements(self, variable):
    ...
    pluscrime = browser.find_element(*AgreementPageLocators.MAIN_SEARCH_PK.format(variable))
```

P.S. Do not add your code as image!!!

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work with the selector being defined in the LocatorsPage and it returns me the error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'.  But it works  to put the locator directly: pluscrime = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "{}")]'.format(variable))